# Problems with login screen kubuntu, lightdm

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, lightdm, login-screen

Recently, I installed xfce on my kubuntu pc, when I got tired of it, I uninstalled it.

Here is where my problem appears, the login screen doesn't get back to normal kde login screen, it becomes a very simple login screen with black background.

I have tried everything, removing gdm, lightdm and kdm and instaling them again but nothing, it is still there, now I have lightdm installed only and it remains te same.

Helppp

MSI GP-70
Kubuntu 14.10
Intel i5 2.50 x 4 GHZ
7.7 GIB Ram

Answer (score 1):

First remove XFCE completely. It seems to have left configuration files.
(sudo apt-get purge xfce)
(sudo apt-get autoclean) (sudo apt-get autoremove)

KDE uses kdm for login screen. You should install it.

Then run sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm.

Comment: That helped me a lot, thank you, it doesn't completly look like the normal one but it sort of solved my problem.